# ravendb search: parenthesis for and/or

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I'm attempting to do a search in raven db.  Currently, I have the following data model.

```
public class DocumentModel
{
    int[] Tag {get;set;}
    int From {get;set;}
    int[] To {get;set;}
}
```

My search parameters will contain a list of tags to search for, as well as a list of user ids that can be in either the from or to field.  I've been able to do a search for whether or not a user is in the From or To field via the Search method and setting the search options to SearchOptions.Or, and I've been able to do the same for Tags.  However, what I need now is

```
(Tag1 || Tag2 ) && (From || To)
```

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Edit: I'm using Linq methods to do the queries, so I'd prefer an answer in that form.

Edit2:  I can have a list of userIds, and a list of tags, but I may have one of the two, both, or neither.  Currently, I've started with a string.join(' OR ') of the tags, put that in a .Search, and do an intersect on a .Search of the e-mail fields.  Is there a better/easier way?

Answer (score 0):

RavenDB fully supports parenthesis, and ordering in this manner.
We recommend using AND / OR but && / || are also supported.

And you can do it in Linq.

Comment: Would you please provide or link to some sample code on how to do this?

Comment: You can do it using standard linq. I 'm not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: session.Query<Foo>().Where(x=> (x.Age == 18 || x.Age == 21) && x.IsFun ).ToList();

Comment: My bad, I didn't give all the requirements.  I can have a list of userIds, and a list of tags, but I may have one of the two, both, or neither.  Currently, I've started with a string.join(' OR ') of the tags, put that in a .Search, and do an intersect on a .Search of the e-mail fields.  Is there a better/easier way?